# Don't see App Extension option in Xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, widget, xcode6, ios-app-extension

I'm working on creating app which has Todays Widget. When i go to Xcode and start new project i don't see the option of "Application Extension" Please check the below screenshots.

[image: Xcode screen shot of new project]

Im using Xcode version 6.3
[image]

Please help me how to enable Application Extension option

For tutorial I'm referring to the following [link](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2014/06/08/explaining-ios-8s-extensions-opening-the-platform-while-keeping-it-secure/)

Thanks you all got the solution for my answer from comments below.

Comment: First of all create project...then in target you see the option Application extension

Comment: Thanks Bhavin got the answer to my question.

Answer (score 14):

After you create New Project.

Goto **File** -> **New** -> **Target**.

You will see all extension options.

Its like this because, you need an app for your extension, you can't just create an extension stand alone.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode -> Preferences -> General -> File Extensions -> Show all**

[image]